# How do you control your publicPath property in vue.config.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I understand how to control what the `publicPath` would be based on `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable.
My `vue.config.js` is working as expected, but only for `production` and non-`production` environments. How would I control the `publicPath` variable when I have `qa`, `dev`, and `stage` environments?

Note: I have added my `.env.qa`, `.env.dev`, and `.env.stage`.

vue.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  ? '/ProductionEnv/'
  : '',
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Simply you need to add another if or change it to switch statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would compute `publicPath` in `vue.config.js` like this:

```js
function getPublicPath() {
  switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    case 'production': return '/ProductionEnv/'
    case 'qa': return '/QaEnv/'
    case 'dev': return '/DevEnv/'
    case 'stage': return '/StageEnv/'
    default: return ''
  }
}

module.exports = {
  publicPath: getPublicPath()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need conditional behavior based on the environment you can use a function and mutate the values inside, or return an object which will be merged.

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      // mutate config for production...
    } else {
      // mutate for development...
    }
  }
}
```

See more here: [configureWebpack](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configurewebpack)